# How to insert specific columns and rows of data to an existing table from one table to another?

Tags: sql-server

Scenario: We have to add a two new columns to a historical table. We already added the new columns to the historical table. At the moment they have no values so they remain NULL. I have another table, that brings in the person_id(PK), timeframe(yyyy) and the two new columns.

task: I need to populate those newly added columns with the values from 2006 onwards.

I never usually run INSERT statements, but I need to insert only those two new columns from 2006 into the historical table. How do I go about doing this correctly? I found the query below, but I guess I am getting stuck in the condition part.  How do I make SQL Server know to insert those rows in the correct year to the correct person for those two new fields?

I know this may seem basic, but I am in the process of learning. Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRcHH.png

````
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;  ```
````

Comment: From your description seems you need an UPDATE, not INSERT. Could you please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @Sergey, I added a picture, all I need is to fill those two new columns in the historical table. I will look into the update statement. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run an **UPDATE** command. Since I don't know what columns you have in your tables I will make some stuff up for the example below.

Let's say you have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (
  id int,
  name varchar(255), 
  age int, 
  fav_color varchar(255), 
  fav_animal varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO people VALUES
(1,'Jim', 30, NULL, NULL),
(2,'Sarah', 43, NULL, NULL),
(3,'Toby', 28, NULL, NULL),
(4,'Sam', 23, NULL, NULL);
```

and then a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fav_stuff (
  id int,
  fav_color varchar(255),
  fav_animal varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO fav_stuff VALUES 
(1, 'Blue', 'Panda'),
(2, 'Red', 'Tiger'),
(3, 'Pink', 'Eagle'),
(4, 'Green', 'Goldfish');
```

These will look like:

```
People:
id  name    age fav_color   fav_animal
1   Jim     30  (null)      (null)
2   Sarah   43  (null)      (null)
3   Toby    28  (null)      (null)
4   Sam     23  (null)      (null)


fav_stuff:
id  fav_color   fav_animal
1   Blue        Panda
2   Red         Tiger
3   Pink        Eagle
4   Green       Goldfish
```

The unique identifier in both these tables is the 'id'. If we wanted to add the fav_stuff data into the appropriate rows of the people table (joining on id) we would write a query like this:

```
UPDATE people p
JOIN fav_Stuff f ON f.id = p.id
SET p.fav_color = f.fav_color, p.fav_animal = f.fav_animal;
```

In the above, we are updating table **people** by joining it with table **fav_stuff** on the **id** and then setting the **fav_color** and **fav_animal** in table **people** to the values from the corresponding columns in table **fav_stuff** where the id's match.

This would result in:

```
people:
id  name    age fav_color   fav_animal
1   Jim     30  Blue        Panda
2   Sarah   43  Red         Tiger
3   Toby    28  Pink        Eagle
4   Sam     23  Green       Goldfish
```